# axios call from express backend not updating in front end, only initial value works

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have an expressjs backend that has an axios call to unbounce that will send the value to the front end, The issue is the value changes over time so I am trying to catch the new value every minute. Right now it will send the initial value but it will not give the updated value without restarting the expressjs backend. Any idea on how to update the state in the front end to show the correct value once per minute.

Front end:

```
import "./App.css";
import axios from "./axios";
import { ProgressBar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {

const [result, setResult] = useState("");

function getInfo() {
  axios.get("api/hello").then((response) => {
    console.log("changed")
    setResult(response.data);
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getInfo()
}, [setResult]);

const total = result/1000000;
const percent = total * 100;
return (
  <main>
      <ProgressBar now={percent} label={`${Math.round(percent)}%`} />
      <div className="test">Some text that shows the result at the end {result}</div>
    </main>
);

}

export default App;
```

Express Backend:

```
const axios = require("axios");    
const cors = require("cors");
const cron = require("node-cron");


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = express();
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(cors());



const getCount = async () => {
    const config = {
        auth: {
            username: 'APIKEY',
        },
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/vnd.unbounce.api.v0.4+json'
        }
    };
    try {
      return await axios.get('https://api.unbounce.com/pages/PAGE_ID', config)
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data)
    }
    
  }

  cron.schedule('* * * * *', function() {
    console.log('getCount Ran');
    getCount();
  });
  
  const countCount = async () => {
    const count = await getCount()
    const isCount = count.data.tests.current.conversions;
  
    if (count) {
      console.log(isCount)
    }

    return server.get("/api/hello", async function (req, res) {
        res.json(isCount);
    });  
  }
    
  


cron.schedule('* * * * *', function() {
  console.log('countCount Ran');
  countCount();
});


server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

The console.log will show the correct value every iteration but the front end just keeps the initial value with no change.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't define a route inside a callback. Why not move the route definition to the top level, then update the frontend to request the count on an interval or similar? Yes it won't update automatically. Either call the endpoint on an interval or if you need realtime updates you need to explore websockets or similar.

Comment: Seems you get the same answer here as you did on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162104/state-not-updating-in-front-end-from-express-js-backend-when-axios-api-call-give). I agree, the route definition in `countCount` seems a little suspect.

Comment: @DrewReese any suggestions to fix it? Ive tried a bunch of things still same issue

Comment: Set the `fetchData` call on an interval to poll the API like was suggested above and in the other question, or use web sockets so the server can push out updates to subscribers as suggested above.